# Как добавить кнопку "купить в 1 клик" woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, wp-theme

хочу добавить к теме xtemos woodmart theme кнопку "купить в 1 клик". Когда нажимаем на ней, открывается всплывающее окно (contact form). Она должна появиться везде где есть кнопка "Добавить в корзину".

> На страницах вроде: "карточка товара", "блок в каталоге, что всплывает при наведении мыши" и "быстрый просмотр" (на скриншотах пример).

Не пойму какие файлы отвечают за это в этой теме. Там так намудрили... Поиск в файлах дал не много информации.

Где искать решение или может конкретно в этой теме кто-то уже решал подобное?

И возможно вы подскажите хук или вроде того, для реализации всплывающего окна по клику на кнопке и что важно, там **должно быть указание выбранного товара** - чтобы я смог обработать его для отправки на почту в связке имя+телефон+выбранный товар.

Премного благодарен откликнувшимся!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: This is StackOverflow in Russian. Please translate your question or use StackOverflow en.

Comment: Так, что ли)) (кнопка 1 клик) https://houselit.ru/product-category/parogeneratory

Comment: Был уверен, что это en версия сайта... Да, верно поняли.

Comment: Переведите вопрос, пожалуйста. Иначе, согласно правилам, он будет закрыт.

Comment: О, уже закрыли. Исправльте текст вопроса, для этого есть кнопка "править" под ним. Тогда будем переоткрывать его.

Comment: Перевел, откройте пожалуйста вопрос

Comment: Я проголосовал за переоткрытие вопроса. Нужно ещё несколько голосов, чтобы он стал открыт снова.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Итак как я решил**:

Необходимо было добавить кнопку в карточку товара и в быстрый просмотр на странице самого магазина.

ПРУФ

[image: ПРУФ]

**Страница магазина**

В этой теме есть файл `woocommerce/content-product-base.php` в папке темы `woodmart`. Копируем этот файл в папку `woodmart-child`, чтобы обновления темы не убивали наши старания.

После строчки `<div class="woodmart-add-btn">` добавляем свою, у меня так:

```
<div class="quick_button">
        <a href="#" type="button" class="button product_type_simple"><span>Купить в 1 клик</span></a>
</div>
```

Далее в самой теме указываем css стили. Я сделал это просто через `custom css`, не трогая файл `style.css` (по сути я скопировал и обновил стили `woodmart-add-btn`)

**Карточка товара**

Здесь все проще. Делаем (если еще нет) в папке темы `woodmart-child` файл `functions.php` и вставляем:

```
function content_after_addtocart_button() {
    echo '<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button">Купить в 1 клик</button>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'content_after_addtocart_button' );
```

Профит. Осталось настроить поведение кнопки.